# iPhone contacts not syncing with Mac OS X Address Book

Tags: macos, itunes, sync, iphone, address-book

I have an iPhone 4 and Mac OS X Lion. In iTunes I have checked *Info > Sync Address book contacts*.

However when I add a new contact to Address Book and click on *sync*, I do not see the new contact on my iPhone.

If I add a new contact on my iPhone, even after syncing I do not see it in my Address Book.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try updating both your Address Book version and your iPhone firmware to the latest. Also, try using Outlook for Mac to [sync iPhone contacts](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3770013) instead.

According to [this](http://forums.techarena.in/portable-devices/1446344.htm) thread, the issue seems to be sourced by Mac's Address book and the way it handles contact info on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a support document that elaborates how to sync your contacts.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1296?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Go to both your iphone and your laptop, and make sure you are syncing all groups.